# Android how to display English for phone with any languages

Tags: android

I'm developing an app and would like to use only English (for now) for all different languages on a user phone.

Is that by default the (values/strings.xml) will be used for all or do I have to copy/replicate all the (values/strings.xml, values-es/strings.xml, values-fr/strings.xml, etc.) with English in them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your English strings in values/strings.xml and all users using your app will see English.

When you are ready to support additional languages, you can refer to [Android doc on language support](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).